# React .map built from 1 of 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So in short, I'm trying to use an array.map that can be called from one of two arrays depending on an if statement. A bit like so

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    foo: [
      {number:"0"},
      {number:"1"},
      {number:"2"},
      {number:"3"}
    ],
    bar: [
      {number:"9"},
      {number:"8"},
      {number:"7"},
      {number:"6"}
    ],
    fooBar: "foo"
  }

  test = () => {
    if(this.state.fooBar === "foo") {
      return this.state.foo
    } else {
      return this.state.bar
    }
  }

  onChangeFooBar = () = {
    this.setstate({fooBar: bar})
  }

  render(){
    <Button onClick={this.onChangeFooBar}>Set to bar</Button>
    <p>Here are some lines of text</p>
    {this.test.map(list => <p> {list.text} </p>)}
  }
}
```

However, it throws an error saying it's not a function.
What is it I'm no getting here? I'm almost certain my issue is in the.test

Comment: As Kind User pointed out, don't forget to add the `return` statement inside your render method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.test` is a function, not an array. Try to call it first:

```
{this.test().map(list => <p> {list.text} </p>)}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something it should be `list.number`, right?

Comment: Bingo. Not sure how I didn't think to do that bit. Thanks

Comment: @Chris You're correct there, I literally chucked that together in 5 mins in notepad++ for this post and missed that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You could as well skip `test()` function and instead write:

`this.state[this.state.fooBar].map(list => <p> {list.number} </p>);`

Comment: Great solution if `this.state.fooBar` takes the same value as the other state keys (either `foo` or `bar`).

Answer (score 0):

Your render function doesn't return anything. Anyways, `test` function is redundant.

Suggested approach:

```
render(){
   const { foo, bar, fooBar } = this.state;
   const r = fooBar === 'foo' ? foo : bar;

   return (
      <Button onClick={this.onChangeFooBar}>Set to bar</Button>
      <p>Here are some lines of text</p>
      {r.map(({ number }) => <p>{number}</p>)}
   )
}
```